# Django template: smartly slice the HTML content

Tags: django, templates, slice

I would like to **smartly** slice an HTML content.

Taking the `news` as an example, the page for displaying a news list is as follows:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Title</th><th>Content</th></tr>
  {% for news in newsList %}
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/news/{{news.id}}/">{{news.title}}</a></td>
      <td>{{news.content | slice:":30" | safe}} ...</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The content of a news is sliced such that the user will only see some part of the news. But if the place of `slice:":30"` happens to be in an HTML tag, there would be a problem.

For example, if the content of `news.content` is the following:

`<p>What is Content Marketing?</p>`

The result of slicing would be `<p>What is Content Marketing?< ...`, in which the tag `<p>` is not closed.

Is there any way to preserve an HTML tag when slicing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should use `truncatechars_html` filter for this
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html